# Match given variable with value from structured JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, match

From a request I have a given variable like

```
realname = "Toni Toni"
```

I have a structured JSON which I call with

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.webside") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

The structure is like

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": {
        "accountStatistics": [{
                    "account": {
                        "name": "Toni Toni",
                        "handle": "toni.k",
                    },
                }, {
                    "account": {
                        "name": "Gina",
                        "handle": "katja.k",}]
                        ...}}
```

What I want is: when my given var "realname" matches with any of the variables "name" in the JSON then create a new variable "username" which contents the string of the variable "handle" (suitable to the "name" it belongs)
so that my result is:

```
realname = "Toni Toni"
username = "toni.k"
```

I found code examples but I am not able to transfer it to my specific problem. I am new to Python. Can somebody help me please?

I tried this one to access, but I got a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`:

```
for ["account"]["name"] in data["result"]["accountStatistics"]:
    if ["name"] ==realname:
        username = account["name"]
        print(username)
```

Comment: `for account in data.result.accountStatsitics: if account.name ==realname: username=account.name break` does this work?

Comment: not really, have I to keep attention with the dots? I mostly assign the values with `data["result"]["accountStatistics"]` -but not sure if it is the best way. 

your thoughts look like what I want, but when I tried this code I got `for account in data.result.accountStatistics:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'result'`

Comment: I know that I can assign the "username" by 
`username = data["result"]["accountStatistics"][0]["account"]["handle"]
print(username)` - but in the end I will have different "realnames" and have to find for all the "realnames" the suitable "handles" (which I will call "username" then)

Comment: try `data['result']['accountStatistics']` instead

Comment: `for account in data["result"]["accountStatistics"]:
    if ["account"]["name"] ==realname:
        username = ["account"]["name"]
        print(username)`

but I got `SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  if ["account"]["name"] ==realname: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  username = ["account"]["name"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if ["account"]["name"] ==realname:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Because `["account"]` is just a list containing the literal string `account` and is completely unrelated to the variable you are looping over.

Comment: but how I have to handle it?

Comment: Please don't add back the commentary about how you wish people would vote on your question. We don't "ban" anyone simply for asking a question, but the merit of your question will and should be judged on whether it is useful and well-defined, not on whether we should feel sorry for you. Votes are to help future visitors find useful content.

Comment: I edited my question like suggested

Comment: You want `account["name"]` not `["account"]["name"]` -- I have not examined the structure in more detail but this should at least provide a starting point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226969/discussion-between-chrissi-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUsernameOf(realname, data)` takes two arguments, the `name` to look for and the JSON to search.

```
import json

handle = open('./data.json')
data = json.load(handle)

def getUsernameOf(realname, data):
    # Match accountStatistics and map over this
    # capturing all `account` objects into a list
    accounts = [x['account'] for x in data['result']['accountStatistics']]
    for account in accounts:
        if account['name'] == realname:
            return account
    return None
```

Using:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": {
        "accountStatistics": [
            {
                "account": {
                    "name": "Toni Toni",
                    "handle": "toni.k"
                }
            },
            {
                "account": {
                    "name": "Gina",
                    "handle": "katja.k"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

as `data.json`, then running with:

```
print(getUsernameOf("Toni Toni", data))
> {'name': 'Toni Toni', 'handle': 'toni.k'}
```

Comment: I think it works, one question: can the variable "realname" exists outside of the def? actually I got back a "None"

Comment: That means it didn't find the name. Don't be tempted to use global variables; instead, have the function `return` whatever you need the caller to know, and assign it to a variable in the caller's scope if you need to remember it.

Comment: @Chrissi It's very strange you got back None. I've posted a complete example, short of the JSON -- all I did to that was to close it, it is exactly the same.

Comment: @kulvin yeah I am sure your code works, I think it's another very basic problem I didn't find. my data base (the JSON) is from a website api and I simplified the JSON for my question to not spam with a large JSON...

Comment: give me some time to try and find my error, I will answer back for sure when it works :-)

Comment: @Chrissi I posted the exact JSON that I am using.

Comment: @kulvin it is like always, I did a stupid typo - sorry! your code works very well!

Comment: @Chrissi Good to hear

Answer (score 1):

The thing after `for` should be the name of a new variable which will contain the next value that you are looping over in each iteration.

```py
for account in data["result"]["accountStatistics"]:
    if account["name"] == realname:
        username = account["name"]
        print(username)
        break  # perhaps
```

Here, we are creating a new variable `account` which will successively take on each value from the list (array) `data["result"]["accountStatistics"]` for the duration of the body of the loop. (When the loop exits, it will refer to the last value it had within the loop. I suggest you `break` out of the loop when you find the value you are looking for if you are certain that it will be unique, or you only need the first hit.)

To see what Python is doing, maybe add `print(account)` right inside the `for` loop; you should be able to observe how the variable takes on a new value from the array each time. (Of course, take out the `print` when you are done debugging.)

Comment: wow, thanks for the very nice explanation :-)